# Error while updating php form information into sql server databases

Tags: php, sql-server, netbeans, pdo, insert-update

I've created forms in php and want to update the data in the sql server database.

Following is my ad.php file.

```
<html>
<title>FORM</title>
<body><br><br>
<form action ="db_connection.php" method="post">
Activity:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
Units: <input id="number"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The data inserted in the above form should be updated in the table 'ad' of the database.

Following is my db_connection.php file:

```
<?php

class DB{
protected static $db;
const SERVER = "";
const SCHEMA = "";
const USER = "";
const PASS = "";
/*
 * Sets up the database connection
 * @return the database instance
 */
public static function databaseConnection(){
    if(!self::$db){
        try {

            $databse = "sqlsrv:server=" . self::SERVER . ";Database=" . self::SCHEMA;
            self::$db = new PDO($databse, DB::USER, DB::PASS);  
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die("Error " . $e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
    return self::$db;
}

}


class ad{

  public function dbAdmin(vat $Activity, int $Units): bool {
    $conn = databaseConnection::getConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ad('Activity', 'Units') VALUES (:Activity, :Units)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Units', $Units);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Activity', $Activity);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $conn->commit();
        return true;
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting a blank page after submitting the form and the database is not updating with the new data being submitted.
Can you please check the code and help me with the corrections.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and you will get an error message. FYI: `databaseConnection` is undefined at the beginning of your `dbAdmin()` method.

Comment: Check your web error log.  Also, I would expect that you have a blank page, since I don't see where db_connection.php writes anything once you post to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reproduce this using Docker. The container "microsoft/mssql-server-linux" is being used.

```
I am using this extension **pdo_sqlsrv** and this driver https://breeto.id.au/2017/05/docker-alpine-linux-php-sql-server/
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label for="activity">Activity: </label>
    <input id="activity" type="text" name="activity">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="number">Units: </label>
    <input id="number" type="number" name="units">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/Db.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Ad.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
ini_set('log_errors', '1');

$post = ['activity', 'units'];
if (!isset($_POST['activity'], $_POST['units'])) {
  header('Invalid form', TRUE, 422);
  exit;
}

$activity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'activity', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$units    = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'units', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if (!is_int($units)) {
  header('A number must be given', TRUE, 422);
  exit;
}

$adTable = new Ad();
$adTable->dbAdmin($activity, $units);

echo '<h1>Done</h1>';
echo "<p>Activity: {$activity}</p>";
echo "<p>Units: {$units}</p>";
```

Db.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);


/**
 * Class Db
 */
class Db {

  protected static $db;

  public const SERVER = 'mssql';

  public const SCHEMA = 'stackoverflow';

  public const USER = 'sa';

  public const PASS = '';

  /**
   * Sets up the database connection
   *
   * @return \PDO
   */
  public static function databaseConnection(): \PDO {
    if (!self::$db) {
      try {
        $dsn      = 'odbc:Driver={FreeTDS};Server=' . self::SERVER . ';Database=' . self::SCHEMA . ';Port=1433';
        self::$db = new PDO($dsn, DB::USER, DB::PASS);
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Error ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }
    return self::$db;
  }
}
```

Ad.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);


/**
 * Class Ad
 */
class Ad {

  public function dbAdmin(string $activity, int $units): bool {
    $conn = Db::databaseConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql  = /** @lang TSQL */
      'INSERT INTO stackoverflow.dbo.ad (Activity, Units) VALUES (:Activity, :Units)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Activity', $activity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Units', $units, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $conn->commit();
      return TRUE;
    }
    $conn->rollBack();
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

SQL Server (Microsoft) Table

```
CREATE TABLE ad
(
  id       INT IDENTITY
    PRIMARY KEY,
  Activity VARCHAR(255),
  Units    INT
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put name attribute in units field too ..as form get submits by its fields name....

Correction :-

```
<html>
<title>FORM</title>
<body><br><br>
<form action ="db_connection.php" method="post">
Activity:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
Units: <input id="number" name="number><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, as it is totally incomplete code.

1. Where is your `$_POST` array ? How and Where are you retrieving the `POST` request data ?
2. `dbAdmin` is method where you are performing data insertion, but how would this method gets called ?? Where are you instantiating the class and calling this method ?
3. What is `vat` data type declared here `dbAdmin(vat $Activity, int $Units)` ??
4. You are missing `name` attribute for `Units` in your html form.